# Run .deb file in Java from file location

Tags: javafx, debian

So I need to run a Debian(.deb) file at some point in my JavaFX program and so I tried using the code below on Linux
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo dpkg -i "+pathToResource.getValue().toString());`

but as you already know that requires me to also pass in the password along somehow for this to work

on Windows I used this sample code here

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToResource.getValue().toString());`

and it whenever administrator privilleges are needed then the software will just request them from the user and everything will run smoothly

But this doesn't seem to work on Linux, it just goes silent and nothing happens,

 I already have an alternative to try to use TerminalFx, but if there's Anyone who knows what an alternative to run the .deb file or any other alternative, I'll be grateful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are some graphical sudos, e.g. gksudo (may be more and I do not know which is the most appropriate for your system). Or you could preemptively ask the user for the password and supply it to the sudo console that opens - needs some tedious work, but is possible I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using shellScript

Here's What I Did

1. Requested the device password from the user through a simple JavaFX stage with just a text field and a submit button.
2. Then I used the password that I just got from the user to create a shell script(Bash)

Here's my sample code to do create the sample shell Script

```
File shell_file = new File("path_to_the_file_where_the_shell_file_will_be_created_at_example_install.sh");
String variableName = "#!/bin/bash\npassword='" + password_from_JavaFx_stage + "'\n" +
                        "echo $password | sudo -S dpkg -i " + path_to_file_to_be_installed;

shell_file.createNewFile()// you can put an if  to check if the function worked and otherwise do some other actions

FileWriter myWriter = new 
FileWriter("path_to_the_file_where_the_shell_file_will_be_created_at_example_install.sh");
myWriter.write(messageContent);
myWriter.close();
```

Then Just run the command using the Processbuilder here's is a sample code to do so

```
String[] command = {String.valueOf(shell_file)};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().command(command);
try {
      Process process = processBuilder.start();

      //read the output
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
      InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String output = null;
                  
      while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
      }
      process.waitFor();

      //close the resources
      bufferedReader.close();
      process.destroy();

}catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So That's the idea and it's my best hope this will save somebody's time and helps out in one way or another.